# Tensorflow save model with config.json

Tags: tensorflow, qupath

I am working on histological applications of ML using a software called QuPath. An extension called Stardist is used to load custom tf models into QuPath, and the Stardist loader requires a pb file with a config.json. According to the keras docs

" The Keras API saves all of these pieces together in a unified format, marked by the .keras extension. This is a zip archive consisting of the following:

A JSON-based configuration file (config.json): Records of model, layer, and other trackables’ configuration.
A H5-based state file, such as model.weights.h5 (for the whole model), with directory keys for layers and their weights.
A metadata file in JSON, storing things such as the current Keras version."

I’m in colab and I ran model.save. I get an empty assets folder, a variables folder, fingerprint.pb, keras_metadata.pb, and saved_model.pb. I'm a little confused as to why there is no config.json. Do I have to convert the keras_metadata.pb to keras_metadata.json?